# dict() function changes the order of elements from a list

Tags: python, dictionary, pyspark

I am having 1 dataframe "csv" as below

```
movieId |               title|              genres|
+-------+--------------------+--------------------+
|      1|    Toy Story (1995)|Adventure|Animati...|
|      2|      Jumanji (1995)|Adventure|Childre...|
```

COMMAND1 : `print("PRINT",csvData.dtypes)`
OUTPUT1 : `('PRINT', [('movieId', 'int'), ('title', 'string'), ('genres', 'string')])`

COMMAND2 : `print ("SAMPLE dictionary**",dict(csvData.dtypes))`

OUTPUT2 :`'SAMPLE dictionary**', {'genres': 'string', 'movieId': 'int', 'title': 'string'}`

after comparing both OUTPUT we can see that dict() function changes the order of elements , how can i avoid that?

Comment: `dict` does not guarantee order (or at least it didn't use to). `collections.OrderedDict` does.

Comment: Python dictionaries are unordered. If you would like an OrderedDict, I suggest that you look at the following: https://pymotw.com/2/collections/ordereddict.html

Comment: To be clear, this is true for Python versions 3.5 and earlier. Dictionaries retain insertion order from 3.6 onward.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Are dictionaries ordered in Python 3.6+?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39980323/are-dictionaries-ordered-in-python-3-6)